# PHP imagick get all images from tiff

Tags: php, imagick

I am trying to load a tiff file and count the number or images and then then dispaly each image as a PNG thumbnail.

The count part is ok it counts 6 which is the correct number of pages in that tif, the code then lists 6 of the same image which is the the first page of  the tiff. Cant workout if there is a problem with my loop or I am simply not using the imagick functions correctly.

Can anyone help

```
<?php

$image2 = new Imagick('http://mysite.org.uk/tiftest/2.tif'); 


/* Create the object */
$image = new Imagick('http://mysite.org.uk/tiftest/2.tif');
$count = $image->getNumberImages();

echo "<h3 style=\"font: bold 12pt Arial\">Total Number of Images Extracted ".
 "from the TIF : ".$image->getNumberImages()."</h3>";

for ($x = 1;$x <= $image->getNumberImages();$x++) {
    $image->pingImage( $image2 );    
    $image->readImageFile( $image2 );    
    $image->setImageFormat( 'png' );
    $image->thumbnailImage(100, 0);
echo "<img id='" . $x . "' src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($image)."' />"; } ?>
```

Comment: Might want to look at the example here http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.nextimage.php

Answer (score 0):

You will have to move to the previous image using `$image->previousImage()`

Iterate over the number of images backwards and move to the previous image to get all of them, might also be able to use `while ($image->hasPreviousImage()) {}` construct

Oh, and dont use readImageFile, you already have the image in-memory.

Answer (score 0):

I sussed it !!

Here is the code to get all the sepearte pages out of the tif and display them as PNG's :

```
<?php
/* Create the object */
$image = new Imagick('http://mysite.o.uk/tiftest/1.tif');
$count = $image->getNumberImages();

echo "<h3 style=\"font: bold 12pt Arial\">Total Number of Images Extracted ".
  "from the TIF : ".$image->getNumberImages()."</h3>";
 $x =0;

foreach ( $image as $image ) {  
    $x++;
    $image->setImageFormat( 'png' );
    $image->thumbnailImage(150, 120);

    echo "<img id='" . $x . "' src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($image)."' />";


 }
?>
```

However now I need to know how to display them as true PNG's without using base63 encoding, any ideas ???